# Evento KeyDown de TextBoxt

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-forms

Estoy trabajando con Visual Studio 2015, windows forms, el problema que tengo es que no entra al evento KeyDow

```
 private void txtCondicionPago_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
        {
            Focus();
        }
    }

    public new bool Focus()
    {
        groupPanel3.Select();
        txtProducto.Focus();
        return true;
    }
```

No entiendo porque no entra al evento.

Comment: ¿Al evento KeyPress o al KeyDown? Porque según el código es el KeyDown el que estás controlando.

Comment: Hola Asier, lo que intento hacer es que cuando presione la tecla ENTER el foco pase a otro control pero no entra al evento KeyDow ni a la condición.

Comment: Comprueba que el controlador del evento está asociado al control (desde la ventana de propiedades del control si lo estás asociando en la ventana de diseño, en tu código si lo estás haciendo por código).
Comprueba que no estés controlando y anulando el evento desde algún control contenedor.

Comment: Asier, lo he solucionado utilizando el evento Leave

Comment: En tiempo de diseño lo he ordenado correlativamente con TabIndex

Comment: En lugar del evento `KeyDown`, tienes que usar el evento `KeyPress`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionado

```
private void txtCondicionPago_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtProducto.Focus();
}
```